# Cancelling multiple alarms?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I have created an events. I have given option for notification before 10 minutes, 30 minutes and before every hour till 12 hours before. I have to set notification for all these intervals.

Now I want to cancel the particular notification if the switch is off. I have given the same intent to cancel the notification. But I think all the notifications got cancelled.

Also I have created time tables and events are created using the time table's id. Now if I delete one time table I want to delete all the notifications set to the events that belongs to the deleted time table.

How can I do this?

**Set notification time function:**

```
public void setNotificationTime(Calendar c)
{

    Date dateFrom = new Date();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        dateFrom = df.parse(startTime);
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {

    }

    dateFrom.getTime();
    c.setTime(dateFrom);

    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if(notificationTime !=null  &&  !notificationTime.isEmpty()) {


        if (notificationTime.equals("10 Minutes Before")) {


            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 10);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
            // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

            SetDay(c);

            notification = c.getTime();
            notificationTime = df.format(notification);

            setAlarm(c);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notificationTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else if (notificationTime.equals("30 Minutes Before")) {

            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 30);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
            // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

            SetDay(c);

            notification = c.getTime();
            notificationTime = df.format(notification);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notificationTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            setAlarm(c);
        } else if (notificationTime.equals("1 Hour Before")) {

            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour - 1);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
            // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

            SetDay(c);

            notification = c.getTime();
            notificationTime = df.format(notification);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notificationTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            setAlarm(c);
        }
```

**Set Alarm function:**

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetmCalen) {


    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

}
```

**Notification cancel on switch off:**

```
 alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

**Notification receiver:**

```
public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


public static int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;

EventTableHelper db;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    db = new EventTableHelper(context);

    List<EventData> testSavings = db.getAllEvents();

    for (EventData ts : testSavings) {
        String log = "from date:" + ts.getFromDate()
                + " ,to date: " + ts.getToDate()
                + " ,location: " + ts.getLocation()
                + " ,title " + ts.getTitle();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        Date date1 = new Date();
        Log.d("Result: ", log);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        try {
            date = df.parse(ts.getFromDate());
            date1 = df.parse(ts.getToDate());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {

        }
        String timeFrom = df2.format(date);
     //   String startTime = String.valueOf(timeFrom);

        String timeTo = df2.format(date1);
       // String endTime = String.valueOf(timeTo);


        String location = ts.getLocation();
        String title = ts.getTitle();


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if(location.equals(""))
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo;

            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        else
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo + "\nAt : " + location;
            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        Log.i("Notify", "Notification");
        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

        myNotification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("notificationId",MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);

        MY_NOTIFICATION_ID ++;

    }
    }
 }
```

Which changes should I do to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create different pending intents and then use particular pending intent to cancel specific alarm .Create your pending intent as usual but add the different flag for different alarm.

```
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1,   intent, FLAG);//Set different value of Flag at the time creating alarm
```

So to make it generic just add one more params in your

```
   setAlarm(Calendar targetmCalen,int flag)
```

Comment: and how to cancel it? as u can see in my set alarm function I have set an pending intent and that i am using in every hours notification to set. Is it fine? Or do i need to create different intent for every hour? Then if i do this. How can I identify which intent is set and which to cancel?

Comment: Also my time table list is another activity. How can I cancel alarms from their of particular events belongs to that time table?

Comment: Idea is simple once again u need to create pending intent with the same flag for which you want to cancel alarm.So to make it generic just add one more params in your setAlar(Calender calender,int flag).And the time of cancel just get flag for that notification ,create pending intent using that and cancel it

Comment: flag as in any int value i can set?

Comment: when i add this    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent,FLAG); in set alarm its showing can not resolve symbol for FLAG

Comment: can you please explain this with my code? @Shakeeb Ayaz

Comment: FLAG is integer variable that you need to declare.
int FLAG=256;// if 30 min
 FLAG=257;//if 15 min

Comment: if i set multiple notifications all comes at one time. @Shakeeb Ayaz